# Can I transfer electricity through induction?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

If I place a solenoid connected to a bulb inside a bigger solenoid which is connected to a power source, will the bulb glow?

Comment: it won't in the static case, but if there are currents varying in time (specifically) in the outer solenoid, then your bulb may glow. The specificity of the time-variance depends on your bulb, whether it is AC, DC, etc.

Comment: @Satwik when you say "AC, DC" I suppose you mean the current, not the bulb. The 2 solenoids form a simple transformer. Hence, if the power source is AC, the bulb's filament will warm up and may glow if there is enough current going through it.

Comment: Yes - if the current in your primary coil varies, a current is induced in the secondary coil. This is how a transformer works